# Can't find variable: URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript

In React Native, I would like to do an abstraction of URLSearchParams so I write this class:

```
export class HttpSearchParamsAdapter extends URLSearchParams implements HttpSearchParams {

constructor() {
    super();
}

set(param: string, val: string): void {
    super.set(param, val);
    }
}
```

But when I build the app, I have this error: Can't find variable: URLSearchParams. I use URLSearchParams from es6.

Comment: How are you importing/defining URLSearchParams?

Comment: I didn't import it

Comment: what's your build step?

Comment: What do you mean? For the moment I use the iPhone emulator of xcode and I build with tsc

Comment: You didn't happen to solve this did you?

Comment: I solve it with polyfill

Comment: @mickaelw, how did you install the polyfill? i mean, where to import it? unlike typical angular projects, ionic doesn't have `polyfills.ts` file.

Answer (score 18):

As mrgoos said, `URLSearchParams` is not supported in iOS which uses [JavaScript Core](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore), you can add a polyfill to React Native.

For example, I had a problem using [wretch](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch), so I used this polyfill globally: [url-search-params-polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill)

```js
// index.js
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';
```

**UPDATE (for React Native 0.59)**

In React Native 0.59, the developers "implemented" some methods of `URLSearchParams` with `throw new Error('not implemented');` so... it miserably fails.

You can read the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922

Instead of the polyfill I used, we can use `whatwg-url` implementation and the `buffer` package as explained here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922#issuecomment-476070032

```js
// index.js
import { URL, URLSearchParams } from 'whatwg-url';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

// react-native 0.59 added its own global URLSearchParams without implementation...
// https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e6057095adfdc77ccbbff1c97b1e86b06dae340b/Libraries/Blob/URL.js#L66
// Issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922
global.Buffer = Buffer;
global.URL = URL;
global.URLSearchParams = URLSearchParams;
```

Answer (score 6):

`URLSearchParams` is not supported in iOS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: Additionally in my case having enabled "Remote JS Debugging" surprisingly made  the `URLSearchParams` working! But shortly after disabling/building production it becomes unusable, unfortunately might be something hard to debug. (RN 0.56)

Comment: The reason remote js debugging makes it work is because that mode will use chrome for the js code and not the actual emulator

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, you can use **react-native-url-polyfill** : https://github.com/charpeni/react-native-url-polyfill

In my case, what I did is :

```
import { URL, URLSearchParams } from 'react-native-url-polyfill';

const url = new URL('https://github.com?param=something');
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
const param = urlParams.get("param");

console.log(param); // will print 'something'
```