# Ionic: Error ReferenceError :Can't find variable: URLSearchParams (abnormal behavior)

Tags: ios, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic and i developed a small app. App is working on Android and browser very well, but when i try to run for ios using  X-code, i get following error,

```
ERROR:ERROR ReferenceError : Can't find variable: URLSearchParams
```

I searched for it and i found that `URLSearchParams is not supported in iOS` as answered in [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298987/cant-find-variable-urlsearchparams)

I was used `URLSearchParams` in three TypeScript files(login.ts, notice.ts, other.ts), i just removed `URLSearchParams` from login.ts and managed `queryString` through string instead of `URLSearchParams` and run my code then whole app running well.

My question is that why i didn't get any error for `URLSearchParams` used in 
 (notice.ts, other.ts), it means that is working well for both file, its something abnormal behavior i found ever

Login.ts

```
let str="";
   str=str+'username='+userData.UserName+'&password='+userData.Password;
```

Notice.ts

```
  let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();  //here error should come, but not error gives
    params.set('deviceId',deviceId);
    params.set('yearId', this.loggedUserData.yearid);
```

Comment: I don't know Cordova/Ionic, Typescript, but it seems that `NSURLQueryItem` (an array of them) is the equivalent on iOS.